# TeXworks on Mac with bib-file?

Tags: texworks

I'm working with TeXworks, and on my Windows machine I had a typesetting called something like "pdflatex+makeindex+bibtex". However, now that I'm working on my Mac that option is not available, so now when I build my tex-file the bibliography isn't working.

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: `pdflatex+makeindex+bibtex` is a script of sorts (actually a built-in binary) in MiKTeX, a Windows-only TeX distribution. On the Mac you could consider other scripts such as `latexmk` (which you'd have to add to TeXworks yourself) or you could just do things by hand: run BibTeX/MakeIndex when you need them.

Comment: if you're on a Mac and use MacTeX, you have the option to use TeXshop. see if this an alternative for you. or you switch to a  more advanced editor like TeXstudio.